# Conflicts with Installing ever since I updated PHP

Tags: php, mysql, centos, gd, yum

Ever since I updated my php (Version 5.6.17), I can't install anything using yum for php (I have CENTOS), without there being a conflict. Any suggestions would be very helpful. It appears there is an older version somewhere I need to get rid of (5.3)

I experience this with both:

```
 sudo yum -y install php-gd
```

AND

```
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

This is the error

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package: php-gd-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.17-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
```

I can't figure this out. Please don't mark as duplicate.

When I update with

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                 |  12 kB     00:00
 * base: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
base                                                                                                                                                          | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00
linuxtech                                                                                                                                                     | 2.6 kB     00:00
remi-safe                                                                                                                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                                                                                                                      | 1.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00
No Packages marked for Update with:

```
 sudo yum install php56w-gd
```

I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                    |  12 kB     00:00     
 * base: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
* epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
* extras: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
* remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
* rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
* updates: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
base       | 3.7 kB     00:00                                                                                                                                                           
extras     | 3.4 kB     00:00                                                                                                                                                   
linuxtech   | 2.6 kB     00:00                                                                                                                                                   
remi-safe   | 2.9 kB     00:00                                                                                                                                                       
rpmforge    | 1.9 kB     00:00                                                                                                                                                      
updates     | 3.4 kB     00:00                                                                                                                                                       
No package php56w-gd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2):

You apparently installed PHP 5.6 from Webtatic repository. I guess (i don't have the list of your installed packages, which you can get with `yum list installed | grep php`), that you need to install these packages with following command:

```
sudo yum install php56w-gd
sudo yum install php56w-mysql
```

and update your php with:

```
sudo yum update php56w
```

(in other words, always use `php56w` in place of `php` with all php-related packages)

Comment: Hi Miro, Thanks for your comment. I get: No package php56w-gd available.

Comment: updates                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00     
No package php56w-gd available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: (The whole thing does not fit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105743/discussion-between-user1011332-and-miro-david).

Comment: Ok i see OP did not updated his post, long story short: php56 was installed from @webtatic, but this repo was already uninstalled from centos. Problem was solved by uninstalling all php related packages, enabling repositories "remi" and "remi-php56" and installing php from there ;)

Comment: Do you have any experience with apache servers?

Answer (score 1):

Yum cannot find this package, because the repository is not enabled.

NOTICE: you should NOT enable both webtatic and remi repository as both provides conflicting packages.

BTW, as I see you already have "remi-safe", I rather recommend you to use "remi-php56" which provide more simple packages (same names than base packages), and more extensions.

See the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)